# Writing a WHILE loop in Java to compute the largest value in a sequence that prevents no user input

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to learn (self-taught) Java by reading Big Java, Late Objects from by Cay Horstmann. I'm using repl.it to write my code (if you may want to look it up, it's public)

A selfcheck question of Chapter 4 Loops is:
How can you overcome the problem of when the user doesn't provide any input in the algorithm of section 4.7.5 (titled Maximum and Minimum) and the WHILE loop just terminates the program for this reason ?

They basically ask to rewrite the code so it solves this problem.

The information of section 4.7.5 you need to solve this problem: To compute the largest value in a sequence, keep a variable that stores the largest element that you have encountered, and update it when you find a larger one.
(This algorithm requires that there is at least one input.)

```
double largest = in.nextDouble();

while (in.hasNextDouble())
{
 double input = in.nextDouble();
 if (input > largest)
 {
 largest = input;
 }
}
```

This is what the book suggests as the answer to this problem (but I disagree):
One solution is to do all input in the loop and introduce a Boolean variable that checks whether the loop is entered for the first time.

```
    double input = 0; 
    boolean first = true; 

    while (in.hasNextDouble()) 
    {   
     double previous = input;   
     input = in.nextDouble();   
     if (first) { first = false; }    
     else if (input == previous)    { System.out.println("Duplicate input"); } 
    }
```

I don't fully understand the first sentence. And I disagree this as a solution for the problem because (as far as I can tell) it tests whether the input has been entered before, instead of testing if any sort of user input has been provided..

I tried to merge those two sections of code together but I can't seem to make it work. Or more specific: figure out how to build it. What variables / loops do I need? In which order do I write this?
I've made a flowchart in Visio of the first section of code but have no clue how to continue.

This is what I've written so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number: ");

    double largest = 0;

    while (input.hasNextDouble())
    {
      double value = input.nextDouble();
      if (value > largest) 
       {
         largest = value;
         System.out.println("The largest input till now is: " + largest);
       }
    }
```

Can someone:

1. Ask me questions which help me to solve this question? I.e. Tell me what tools I need (WHILE, FOR etc.)
2. Provide a solution in text which I can hopefully transform in code
3. Or write the code for me (I haven't learned arrays yet, so please solve it without)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you saying if the user does not provide an input on the "Enter the number: " line?

Comment: Yes as far as i can tell that's what they want. 
A loop (that computes/stores the largest input) that works without any user input. I can send you a screenshot of the question (+ provided answer) in the book if you want to (and if StackOverflow accepts this??)

Comment: Your code have the following problem - you will not be able to distinguish between the cases when 0 is a legitimate maximum and when it simply indicates the lack of input.

Comment: I've changed it to:
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
 double largest = input.nextDouble();

    while (input.hasNextDouble())
    {
      double value = input.nextDouble();
      if (value > largest) 
      {
        largest = value;
        System.out.println("The largest input till now is: " + largest);
      }
    }

Does this solve the problem you're pointing out PM 77-1?

Answer (score 0):

So I worked on this for a bit and I think I have something close to what you're looking for using a do while loop.

This code accepts user input first, then checks it's value in comparison to the last input and return either "Input a higher value", "Duplicate number found", or it sets the last number entered to the current number.

I hope this helps you get your code to where you'd like it to be! I'm still new, so I apologize if this is not entirely optimized.

Also, I have not added a way to exit the loop, so you may want to add a check on each iteration to see if the user would like to continue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double userInput = 0;
    double prevNum = 0; 
    boolean hasValue = false;
    boolean exitCode = false;

    do {        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        userInput = sc.nextDouble();

        do {
            if (userInput<prevNum) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number higher than " + prevNum);
                hasValue=true;
            }
            else if (userInput==prevNum) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate input detected.");
                hasValue=true;
            }
            else {
                prevNum = userInput;
                hasValue = true;
            }
        }
        while(hasValue==false);

        System.out.println(prevNum);
        System.out.println(userInput);

    }
    while(exitCode==false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want compute if the number entered is the largest entered from the beginning but declare it at the largest if it's the first iteration then do this :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean flag = true;
    double largest = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
    while (input.hasNextDouble()){
        double value = input.nextDouble();
        if (flag) {
            flag = false;
            largest = value;
        }    
        else if (value > largest) largest = value;
     System.out.println("The largest input till now is: " + largest);
     System.out.println("Enter a new number: ");
    }
}
```